# Cleaning a stubborn Electrospray residue

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, precipitation

I have an electrospray ionization capillary tip that sprays into a chamber that contains some circuit boards. An aqueous CsI sample is apparently causing a white residue to build up on these boards after some time. I thought the residue was the salt itself, but I can't dissolve it with water. I tried methanol and that didn't work either. Does anyone know what this could be and how to clean it? I'm worried about excess build up over time.

I considered that it might be CsOH, but that should also rinse away with water because its so soluble.

Comment: Most likely impurities in the water, although some soft glasses can dissolve a bit in water (cactus,maize and some sponges reinforce their structure from dissolved silica). How pure is the water you use? Are any cleaning material residues left in the apparatus?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - The water used is millipore water. However, the syringe has contained R6G before. it was rinsed and sonicated with MeOH thoroughly.

Comment: Millipore have various devices. What is the level of dissolved solids??

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - This is 18 Mohm millipore and we are using mM levels of CsI. When we use something other than CsI we don't get this build-up, so I'm pretty sure it's related to the CsI somehow. Also some relevant information that I omitted before by mistake: these boards are gold-plated, and as I understand it there may be an alloy forming? As for cleaning materials, I have only used water and MeOH, with some rubbing with a cotton cleaning tip.

Comment: Then I'd look to possible contamination in the CsI. Put a few drops of the plain conductivity water and a few drops of CsI solution on *clean* microscope slides and evaporate in a desiccator, then wash the slides with water and MeOH as you normally do. There should be no resdue.